# Is there a way to hide parts of an object?

Tags: modeling

I currently am modeling a roof and the roof plates are overhanging at the corner. I marked the parts I want to hide.

[image]

Is there maybe the possibilty to place a Box or another object on those parts and tell the mesh that all parts of the object that overlap with the Box should be hidden?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use boolean modifier to cut volumes with other volumes.

(In the pictures below, the black object has faces and is set to wireframe display for better overview.)

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: It would very helpful if you could add some explanation as to *how* to set up the boolean  modifer; those pictures aren't very descriptive.

Comment: I know they aren't, but I think it makes no sense to give a complete introduction of the boolean modifier every time some ask about it. This post shows what is does and how it is called, not how it is used. Anyone can look that up in lots of sources elsewhere.

Comment: @Dimali sure, there is a line, I know:) But mostly it's about balance, imho including the modifier panel in the screenshot would increase the value a lot with not so much extra work. It makes sense to include the info that the user likely does not have (sometimes with link to another answer or including it fully). I've seen some answers from you even with gif animations, so it's not like you don't know how to put up quality content:)

Comment: I think this is a relevant concern (see my recent post on the meta). Is it better to mark it as duplicate than to give a short answer?